# Woocommerce prevent custom form field being looged with order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have added a few custom checkout fields to woocommerce checkout page.

One of them is used solely to provide a check on the page and does not need to be logged with the order when placed.

What hook would I use to prevent that field from being added to the address_flexible_checkout_fields value in the order edit page on the backend?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a field visually (and perhaps process it) but never actually save the data. It's basically this tutorial with the save step omitted: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-7

Add a field to the end of your checkout with the `woocommerce_after_order_notes` hook:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

If the field is required you can process it and throw an error message if left empty:

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted and possibly vote it up.

Comment: Many thanks - I already have the form field in place and it gets sent with the order but I need to prevent it from doeing so. I think the problem is that it was added via Woocommerce Checkout Fields admin which seems to lump all additional fields together (i need 2 out of the 3 sent). Looks like I'll have to try to add this one using the process here instead so will try to check if that works